# Open a specific version of Visual Studio in safe mode

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2019

I want to open my Visual Studio 2019 in Safe mode using below command.But, Visual studio 2015 professional gets opened instead of VS 2019 community edition. How to set **devenev** to open VS 2019 always?  (Note: My VS 2019 closed immediately after I open a solution in it, I want to open it in safe mode to check that issue originally)

> Run command I tried :devenv.exe /safemode

Comment: You have more than one devenv.exe file on your machine.  You're running the wrong one.  Put a "cd" in front of it to navigate to the vs2019 install directory or use the correct Developer Command Prompt.

Comment: I tried already running devenv in VS 2019 command prompt but it does not worked.